# ASP.NET Core Entity Framework relationship issue - Why no cascade delete and migration issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm building an app that trainers can create heroes.

1. A trainer can have as many heroes as he wishes.
2. Every hero must have a trainer (no hero without a trainer).
3. A hero has only one trainer - no shared heroes

The trainer model:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Hero> Heroes { get; set; }
}
```

The Hero model

```
[Table("Heroes")]
public class Hero
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
    public string AppUserId { get; set; }
}
```

The DataContext:

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

I don't really understand why when I'm creating the migration. the results are:

[image]

I wish the `AppUserId` column to be: `nullable: false`

And `onDelete` method of the hero to be: `ReferentialAction.Cascade`

I'm very confused about how to solve it and why it's happening. Might someone have an idea of how to solve this and why is happening?

And another question, since my `AppUser` id is type string (IdentityUser type) should I make the id of the hero a string as well or int? Are there any benefits for each of them?

Comment: Have you got any entity configuration code? If not, then you need to write some to set things up the way you want them.

Answer (score 0):

The configurations you see in the migration are all the default behaviours. The `AspUserId` column is nullable because strings in .NET can be null. The same goes for the referential action, and cascade delete will never be the default behaviour for that (and I would strongly recommend not using cascade delete, but that's opinion-based)

To change the default configuration you need to set up your entities. There are various ways to do that (data annotation attributes, fluent API and the `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` interface) but let's pick the fluent API here. In your context, simply override the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // First lets tell EF that the AspUser property is required
    modelBuilder.Entity<Hero>()
        .Property(h => h.AppUser)
        .IsRequired(true);


    // Second, we can tell EF that you want to enable cascade delete for the relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Heroes)
        .WithOne(x => x.AppUser)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

***Note**: I wrote the above from memory so the cascade delete line may not be 100% accurate, also I'm not entirely sure what you wanted to be deleted, so made a guess.*